# Simple, Restricted, Unrestricted Random Sampling term clarification

Tags: statistics

I've been studying some statistics and am becoming increasingly confused by the different terms, mostly because the definitions for the different ones, what something is called, varies depending on what source you get it from. For example, my first statistics textbook defines:

> Simple random sample: One taken with replacement
>
> Unrestricted random sample: One taken without replacement

But then the next textbook in the same series defines the terms as:

> Simple random sampling: Done without replacement.

On the internet definitions are equally inconsistent. If anyone who knows for sure could define these terms (do official definitions exist?) that would be very helpful.

Comment: If you're taking a simple random sample, you don't have to necessarily do it with or without replacement. However, usually simple random samples are done without replacement because we typically don't want to get information from the same individual twice.

Comment: To me, a simple random sample is one where each member of the population is equally likely to be sampled; an unrestricted sample is similar in that there is not a system such as stratified or systematic sampling.  My presumption is that such a sample from a finite population would be without replacement unless stated otherwise

Comment: This confusion/disagreement about the use of 'restricted' vs 'unrestricted' infests not only sampling theory but also ANOVA modeling. It seems many authors who haven't thought deeply about it are just copying from other sources. Those who have thought deeply seem to disagree what the terms mean or ought to mean. About 5-10 years ago there were articles in statistics journals arguing various points of view. None lately. Maybe journal editors got tired of wasting space on it. Practical consequences seem rare. Should vote to close as 'opinion based', but maybe too soon for that.